# how to build conditional forms?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

All I want to do is disable 'toDate' input field in my form when the user selects roeType as 'Daily ROE' from the dropdown.How to achieve this is model driven forms of angular2.

```
createAddROEForm() {
this.addRoeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  roeTypeId: [],
  roeType: [],
  roeSource: [],
  supplierName: [],
  fromDate: [],
  toDate: [{value:'', disabled:(this.addRoeForm.value.roeType='Daily ROE')}],
  status: [],
  reason: [],
  companyMarket: [],
  productCategory: ['',Validators.required],
  productSubType: ['',Validators.required],
  productName: ['',Validators.required],

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 toDate: [{value:'', disabled: this.addRoeForm.value.roeType==='Daily ROE'}],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]='addRoeForm'>
<select (change)="dummyMethod()">
 <option></option>
<select>
</form>
```

From HTML call a method in this case dummyMethod()

```
dummyMethod(){
if(this.addRoeForm.get('roeType').value == 'Daily ROE'){
this.addRowForm.controls.toDate.disable();
}}
```

and define the method inside the component.ts file's class.